# Как из button_click например считать массив и записать в класс?

Tags: c#

[image: Здесь я создал класс и массив в button_click но вариант с методом CopyTo не сработал]

```
class one
    {
        public double[] arr;
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double[] array = new double[5] {1,2,3,4,5};
        one One = new one();
        array.CopyTo(One.arr);
    }
```

Comment: Ошибка то какая?

Comment: У метода CopyTo нет перегрузки принимающей один параметр, укажите элемент массива, с которого начинать копирование

Comment: Всмысле? Напиши как это сделать

Comment: @XARiN `array.CopyTo(One.arr, 0);`

Comment: Понял, но компилятор не обрабатывает это: https://prnt.sc/X8aW1EgzIGEC

Comment: Не употребляйте слова, значения которых вы не понимаете. Компилятор это прекрасно обработал. Код был успешно скомпилирован. Исключение выброшено в процессе выполнения. Потому что массив `arr` не создан. Задайте ему значение `new double[array.Length]`.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо